# Compute capability of a small (1mm^2) ASIC

Tags: cpu-architecture, processor, riscv

I was watching a recent ACM Turing Lecture by Hennessy and Patterson and was intrigued by a stat they cited on the cost of small chip tape-outs. They claimed that you can tape-out 100 1 mm x 1mm chips at 28 nm process node for $14,000, presumably on a test shuttle.

My question is, if I wanted to fill this chip area with MAC units (say 16 or 32 bit), how many simultaneous MACs could I do per cycle?

Comment: Programmable with inputs coming from a RISC-V instruction stream?  Or pure fixed-function chains or integer multiply-accumulate just arranged to prove a theoretical point about density without necessarily computing anything useful or in the most efficient way?

Comment: You better post this to the [Electrical Engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/36283/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a back of the envelope calculation, [this paper](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:22435/fulltext01.pdf) describes a 32x32->64 multiplier as being 435um*482um in Synopsys' 90nm educational technology.  If you just trivially scale to 28nm, you get 0.02mm^2 per instance.  That's probably within an order of magnitude, which is good enough because "multipliers per mm" isn't really a meaningful metric: the interesting part is how to get data into and and out of such a multiplier array, which will dominate the area of the actual multipliers.

For another reference, the FU540-C000 is 30mm^2 in TSMC's 28nm HPC process.  [Yunsup's HotChips presentation from last year](https://www.hotchips.org/wp-content/uploads/hc_archives/hc29/HC29.21-Monday-Pub/HC29.21.20-IOT-Embedded-Pub/HC29.21.210-Freedom-SoCs-Lee-SiFive-v2.pdf) shows a fairly detailed die plot on page 17, from which you can calculate what 1mm^2 gets you on a modern technology -- it's quite a bit of SRAM/logic, but not many pads.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the dominance of the data path. It seems like not much can be done in just 1mm x 1mm.